# how to use the $.param in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched the net already and the only useful information is in the jquery site itself,

I have this code:

```
var param = { branch_id : branch_id};
var str = $.param(param);
alert(str);
```

but the output of that when logged or alerted is:

```
branch_id=1234 + //lets say for example 1234 is the value.
```

Why is there a plus sign there? that is my question.

Comment: what u want as output ?

Comment: Neither me, even with console.log.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dFeX8/ works fine. It also means you haven't pasted all your code.

Comment: The example you've posted doesn't alert an `+`. Something must be missing...

Comment: Make sure no white space in your data (branch_id)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because your `branch_id` contains a space at the end:

```
"1234 " // => 1234+
```

Take a look at source [code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.param) of `jQuery.param`.

So the space is first converted to `"%20"` using `encodeURIComponent` and after that jQuery.param replaces is with a plus sign:

```
return s.join("&").replace(r20, "+");
```

You can trim input value to avoid this redundant + or maybe cast value to a number.

Comment: Well duh, of course! A space is (url-)encoded as a `+`. Good find +1

Comment: By the way: `var r20 = /%20/g`